# How to add special keys to a keylogger python

Tags: python, keyboard, keypress

How do I add multiple special keys for example backspace,enter and other special keys in python with the use of exception when creating a keylogger in pycharm

I used an if statement for the special key space. But when I tried the rest on the other special keys it did not work

This is the code I used for the special key space:

```
def process_key_press(self,key):
  try:
    current_key = str(key.char)
  except AttributeError:
    if key == key.space:
      current_key = " "
  else:
   current_key = " " + str(key) + " "
```

The output for this special key space code worked.
How do I get the same output for the other special keys like backspace,enter and other keys.

Comment: I guess you're looking for a general solution, instead of having to check for each key type? also, how do you want to represent the backspace key? there is no such thing as a backspace escape sequence.

Comment: Please can you help me achieve that by showing me code to do that in pycharm